# Gridengine: error: commlib error: got select error (connection refused)

Tags: sungridengine

I just installed gridengine & getting error when doing `qstat`:

```
error: commlib error: got select error (Connection refused)
error: unable to send message to qmaster using port 6444 on host "MyHost-VirtualBox": got send error
```

`cat /var/spool/gridengine/qmaster/messages` gives:

```
main|"MyHost-VirtualBox"|W|local configuration "MyHost-VirtualBox" not defined - using global configuration
main|"MyHost-VirtualBox"|E|global configuration not defined
main|"MyHost-VirtualBox"|C|setup failed
```

setting `export SGE_ROOT` and running `sudo service /etc/init.d/gridengine-master start` didn't help. I think the service isn't running. Should I setup more env variables or a setup file?

Running on Ubuntu. Installed by `sudo apt-get install gridengine-master gridengine-client` and accepted all defaults.

Comment: I got this error because I cleaned all my environment variables (except a few, like `SGE_ROOT`, but probably I cleaned some which should be there). When I leave all env vars as-is, it works. Unfortunately I cannot tell which of the envs were important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the setup issues went away when installing the Debian version.
need version 8 since debian is ver 8 & only debian master works ( gridengine-master_8.1.9+dfsg-8_amd64.deb).